# How to get the first group from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a itemlocation table like:

```
item     address  date
a        x        1
b        x        1
a        y        2
b        y        2
...
```

I want to return the result set of

```
item     address  date
a        x        1
b        x        1
```

where it includes all the items at the *first* address group order by date.

I was looking at something similar to rownum but it's for the first in the group, not the first group of a table. Something like:

```
select * from (select * from itemlocation group by address order by date) where group_number <= 1;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `rank()` to find all the rows with the earliest date and then filter by `rnk_dte = 1`

```
select  item
       ,address
       ,"date"
from   (
       select  t.*
              ,rank() over(order by "date") as rnk_dte
       from   t
       ) t
where  rnk_dte = 1
```

| ITEM | ADDRESS | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 1 |
| b | x | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ia4Pp3Vw)

Comment: In my case I need to rank() on address, but it works thanks!